# A cleaner way to create a header/content CSS Grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a fairly simple site layout but being new to CSS Grid, I'm pretty sure I'm going about it the wrong way.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 120px 450px;
}

.header,
.main {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.side {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="side">Should have the same background color/gradient as header</div>
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <div class="side">Should have the same background color/gradient as header</div>
  <div class="side">Should have the same background color/gradient as Content</div>
  <main class="main">Content</main>
  <div class="side">Should have the same background color/gradient as Content</div>
</div>
```

This is sort of what I'm going for: a header and a main section, with the content of both kept to the center of the page - but at the same time I want the whole of both rows to have their own background colors. But my solution uses a bunch of unneeded divs and the use of `grid-template-rows: 150px 450px;` is wrong too since I want the content to take up the rest of the page not 450px.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving max-width and margin to the container class

```
 .container{
     max-width:calc( (3/5) * 100vw);
     margin:0 auto; 
     grid-template-rows: 120px 1fr; 
     display:grid;
  }
```

Comment: so you simply copied a portion of my code and you also got upvoted .. strange

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  min-height:100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red, blue) top/100% 120px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(green, grey) bottom/100% calc(100% - 120px) no-repeat;
}
body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 120px 1fr;

}

.header,
.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <main class="main">Content</main>
</div>
```

And if it's the only content you will have inside body you can also use `max-width` and `vw` unit like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red, blue) top/100% 120px no-repeat, /*Cover the header*/
    linear-gradient(green, grey) bottom/100% calc(100% - 120px) no-repeat; /*Cover the content*/
}
.container {
  /* you want 1f 3fr 1fr so we have 5fr so we need (3/5)*/
  max-width:calc( (3/5) * 100vw);
  margin:auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 120px 1fr;
  min-height:100vh;
}

.header,
.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <main class="main">Content</main>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with more info. Please refer to it.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain whats going on in background and max-width?

Comment: Also I'm not a fan of how you did the background gradient on the body element. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty I added some explanation for the max-width .. for the gradient this is the simpliest solution is you want to avoid a lot of code, multiple gradient to cover the top and bottom part ... if you don't like it you have to use more element or pseudo element and the result will be the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 150px; 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header-container, .content-container {
  display: contents;
}

.header-container div {
  background: #ddd;
}

.content-container div {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='header-container'>
      <div class='side'>Side</div>
      <div class='header'>Header</div>
      <div class='side'>Side</div>
    </div>
    <div class='content-container'>
      <div class='side'>Side</div>
      <div class='content'>Content</div>
      <div class='side'>Side</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```